# TypeError: X is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function in the parent component:

```
const App = () => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const handleRef = () => {
    console.log('ref clicked');
    if (ref.current !== null) {
      ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  };
  return(
    <Header handleRef={handleRef} />
  )
```

which is passing down `handleRef` to `Header`:

```
const Header = ({ handleRef }: any) => {
  return (
    <Navigation items={data} handleRef={handleRef} />
  )
}
```

which is passing down `handleRef` to `Navigation`:

```
const Navigation = ({ items }: any, { handleRef }: any) => (
  <div
    className="navigationItem"
    onClick={() => {
      handleRef();
    }}
    onKeyDown={handleRef}
    role="button"
    tabIndex={0}
  >menu item</div>
)
```

But onClick raises `Uncaught TypeError: handleRef is not a function`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props are passed down to components as a *single object*, not multiple objects.

```
const Navigation = ({ items }: any, { handleRef }: any) => (
```

should be

```
const Navigation = ({ items, handleRef }: any) => (
```

You should also not use `any`, since that defeats the whole purpose of TypeScript. The `items` looks to be some sort of an array, and the `handleRef` is a function that takes no arguments and returns nothing, so you should have something like

```
const Navigation = ({
  items,
  handleRef
}: {
  items: Array<Item>; // insert the type of an array item here
  handleRef: () => void;
}) => (
```

Comment: Thanks, it's obvious now that I see the solution. And you're right about types, I used `any` to first understand how `useRef` and `forwardRef` works.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing props incorrectly. From the definition of your Navigation component, it's expecting two objects instead of one with two keys. Try this:

```
type Props = { 
  handleRef: () => void;
  items: unknown[]; // replace "unknown" with the correct type
};

const Navigation = ({ handleRef, items }: Props) => (
  ...
);
```

Note that you shouldn't be using `any` because that bypasses the type checks and takes away the benefits of using typescript in the first place.